# Custom iPhone analytic tool

Tags: iphone, analytics

Do you think that if I'll build my own custom analytic tool (Flurry, Pinchmedia) and I'll host that on the same server where I have my data source for the application, will Apple consider this as a thirdparty analytic tool or not? ... Problem is that Flurry and Pinch are being banned from Appstore by the newest T&C ... than I thought that I'll build an open source library that will allow anyone to have their own analytic installed on their server ...

Thanks,

Ondrej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Full disclosure: I work for Localytics)*

What you describe would seem to comply with Apple's new terms. It's what I call **1st-party collection of device data**. Or Apple could approve your use 3rd-party analytics, which is more likely if your analytics service isn't using those data to serve ads or selling data to someone else.

But why build it yourself? Localytics announced its Enterprise analytics service last week, which includes 1st-party data collection: http://www.localytics.com/blog.  Localytics client libraries for iPhone (and Android and BlackBerry) are **already open source**.